# Why I get the error: list index out of range

Tags: python

```py
def sum13(nums):
  summ = 0
  for i in range(1, len(nums)):
    if nums[i] != 13 and nums[i-1] != 13:
     summ += nums[i]
  if nums[0] != 13:
    summ += nums[0]
  return summ
```

The error is produced by the last `if` and I don't understand why

Comment: how does your `nums` look like?

Comment: `nums` is empty. Is there a reason you decided not to share all of the information given in the error?

Comment: sum13([1, 2, 2, 1])

Comment: @Sayse that s the only error I get list index is out of range, but when i delete the last if it compiles

Comment: Works for me with `sum13([1, 2, 2, 1])`. Please check if the code you presented here is the code you're running.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first check `print( len(nums) )` - probably you get `0` so you have empty list and you can't get first element `nums[0]` because it doesn't exist - and you get error because you try to get element which doesn't exist. BTW: if you add print inside `for` loop it will not print it because it never execute this loop - `range(1,0)`  will not execute loop - so it never try to use `nums[i]` and not raise error.

Comment: this problem is from CodingBat -> python -> List-2 sum13, can you check the code there aswell @Matthias

Comment: You forgot the following from the task: "returning 0 for an empty array". After you fixed that you'll see that your other code doesn't meet the expactations of the task.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means `len(nums) == 0`. Try something like

`if nums and nums[0] != 13:`

Comment: It means `bool(nums) is True`(which means nums is not a empty list in your case) and `nums[0] != 13` is true, too. Note that the order of the conditions matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python `enumerate`, rather than a loop counter, to track your position in the array you can simplify the code to have a single `if` statement, and eliminate the error if the length of the list is zero:

```py
def sum13(nums):
    summ = 0
    for ix, num in enumerate(nums):
        if ix == 0 or (num != 13 and nums[ix-1] != 13):
            summ += num
    return summ
```

When `nums` is empty, the `for` loop won't execute at all.

Because Python uses 'early termination' in the evaluation of `if` statements, it means that as soon as it detects that `ix == 0` is True, it won't evaluate `nums[ix-1]` when `ix` is 0.

Comment: Wow didn't know about the  _enumerate_  function thanks for your answer, David!